# How to plot subcategory with multiple values in a bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I would like to plot data in a dictionary called `data`. For each category, I'd like to have subcategory of `positive` and `negative`. The problem is that each of these should have multiple values. The end result should be like this:

[image: Bar plot sketch]

```
data = {'A': {'pos': [3, 5, 7], 'neg': [8, 10, 11]},
        'B': {'pos': [4, 7, 8], 'neg': [7, 10, 12]},
        'C': {'pos': [1, 3, 4], 'neg': [2, 8, 8]}}
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulty here is that you lack an index for your `pos` and `neg` values.

You can create one from scratch:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dict = {'A': {'pos': [3, 5, 7], 'neg': [8, 10, 11]},
        'B': {'pos': [4, 7, 8], 'neg': [7, 10, 12]},
        'C': {'pos': [1, 3, 4], 'neg': [2, 8, 8]}}

shift = 0

for key in dict:
    dict[key]['index_pos'] = np.arange(0+shift,len(dict[key]['pos'])+shift)
    dict[key]['index_neg'] = np.arange(0+len(dict[key]['pos'])+shift,len(dict[key]['neg'])+len(dict[key]['pos'])+shift)
    shift+=len(dict[key]['neg'])+len(dict[key]['pos'])
```

Then convert your dictionary to a pandas dataframe:

```
list_of_dataframes = []
for i, key in enumerate(dict):
    print(key)
    df_temp = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict[key])
    df_temp['group'] = i
    list_of_dataframes.append(df_temp)
df = pd.concat(list_of_dataframes)
```

And plot the pos and neg values using matplotlib `bar` function:

```
plt.bar(df['index_pos'], df['pos'], color='green', label='pos')
plt.bar(df['index_neg'], df['neg'], color='red', label='neg')
plt.legend()
```

*Et voilà*:

[image]

I will leave it to you to fix the labels and the spacing between categories (hint: try adjusting the `shift` variable).